# ORA-01417 - Two outer joins error. New join syntax?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I never got my head around the "new" SQL join syntax, and therefore use the "old" join system, with the (+). I know it's about time I learned it - however I just find the old syntax a lot more intuitive, especially when working with multiple tables with multiple joins.

However I now have an operation which requires two outer joins on the same table. My code is:

```
SELECT
    C.ID,
    R.VALUE,
    R.LOG_ID,
    LOG.ACTION
FROM
    C,
    R,
    LOG
WHERE
    C.DELETED IS NULL
    AND R.DELETED IS NULL
    -- Two joins below
    AND R.C_ID(+) = C.ID
    AND R.LOG_ID(+) = LOG.ID
```

However this results in an error:

ORA-01417 - A table may be outer joined to at most one table.

Searching for this error I find that the solution is to use the new syntax For example this answer on SO:
[Outer join between three tables causing Oracle ORA-01417 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303534/outer-join-between-three-tables-causing-oracle-ora-01417-error)

So I am aware that some may consider this question a duplicate as it technically already has an answer. However the "old" syntax posed in that question does not contain exactly the same number of tables and joins as I have here, and try as I might, I'm not sure how I would factor this in to my own code.

Is anyone able to assist? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should get used to the "new" syntax that is used for more than 25 years now since it is already in the 1992 SQL standard.

Comment: You have no join conditions between LOG and C; is this right?

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to use the "new" syntax for outer joins and stop using the proprietary `(+)`  operator.

Comment: The fact is, old syntax can be ambiguous (because it defines the join on columns). New syntax is not (because it defines the joins on tables)

Comment: I hear you on making the switch - I used to think the old way was easier to "compute" and the new way almost impenetrable, but in reality, once I made the switch, it was actually very simple and logical (even if it did cause me to have a different mental picture of how I think of joins). I totally recommend switching to the new syntax - it's clearer, for a start (all your join conditions are with the tables they're joining), and much less prone to unintentional cross joins (it's very easy to forget to add join conditions when you add them as predicates). And the new style is more flexible!

Comment: @Aleksej - Correct. They are linked via R.

Comment: What is your question? "Is anyone able to assist?" is not on-topic. The error message says what is wrong. Write some legal code that does what you want & when stuck give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.). Innumerable sources explain LEFT JOIN. PS Give your SQL version. Recent changes allow some table reuse with (+).

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @ChrisMelville LOG and C are not linked via R. Your query would fetch all rows from LOG. Maybe you typed `R` and `LOG` the wrong way around in the last line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT C.ID, R.VALUE, R.LOG_ID, LOG.ACTION
FROM C LEFT JOIN
     R 
     ON R.C_ID = C.ID LEFT JOIN
     LOG
     ON R.LOG_ID = LOG.I
WHERE C.DELETED IS NULL AND
      R.DELETED IS NULL;
```

The "new" (it is 25 years old) outer join syntax is actually very easy to follow, particularly for a simple example with just `LEFT JOIN`.

The idea is you want to keep all rows from one table (perhaps subject to filters in the `WHERE` clause).  That is the first table.  Then you use a chain of `LEFT JOIN` to bring in other tables.

All rows from the first table are in the result set.  If there are matching rows in the other tables, then columns from those tables come from matching rows.  If there are no matches, then the row from the first table is kept.

Comment: This is not correct, (as you know) each subsequent join uses as its left table the result of the preceding joins, not the 1st table of a "chain". Presumably you are trying to say something about a special case involving FKs, but this isn't saying it.

Comment: The original version implicitly cross joins to `log` and so could give different results.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, we can now test this as the ORA-01417 restriction was lifted in 12c.

Sample data:

```
create table c (id primary key, deleted) as
select 1,   'Y'     from dual union all
select 2,   null    from dual union all
select 3,   'Y'     from dual union all
select 4,   null    from dual;

create table l (id primary key, action) as
select 101, 'One'   from dual union all
select 102, 'Two'   from dual union all
select 103, 'Three' from dual union all
select 104, 'Four'  from dual;

create table r (c_id references c, log_id references l, value integer, deleted varchar2(1));

--Generate some sample data:
insert into r (c_id, log_id, value, deleted)
select c.id, l.id, rownum * 100, c.deleted
from   c cross join l;

--Add some more rows to L not linked to anything:
insert into l values (105, 'Five');
insert into l values (106, 'Six');

commit;
```

Original query and results in 19c:

```
select c.id, r.value, r.log_id, l.action
from
    c, r, l
where
    c.deleted is null
    and r.deleted is null
    -- Two joins below
    and r.c_id(+) = c.id
    and r.log_id(+) = l.id
order by 1,2,3,4;

  ID      VALUE     LOG_ID ACTION
---- ---------- ---------- ------
   2        500        101 One
   2        600        102 Two
   2        700        103 Three
   2        800        104 Four
   2                       Five
   2                       Six
   4       1300        101 One
   4       1400        102 Two
   4       1500        103 Three
   4       1600        104 Four
   4                       Five
   4                       Six

12 rows selected
```

Notice that as @Alexej pointed out in a comment, `l` is not filtered so we get all rows from it, then we outer-join `r` to the result of that. (This might have been clearer if the original `from` clause had been written in the logical join order `c, l, r`.)

Rewritten using the shiny new 1990s syntax:

```
select c.id, r.value, r.log_id, l.action
from   c
       cross join l 
       left join r
            on  r.c_id = c.id
            and r.log_id = l.id
where  c.deleted is null
and    r.deleted is null
order by 1,2,3,4;

  ID      VALUE     LOG_ID ACTION
---- ---------- ---------- ------
   2        500        101 One
   2        600        102 Two
   2        700        103 Three
   2        800        104 Four
   2                       Five
   2                       Six
   4       1300        101 One
   4       1400        102 Two
   4       1500        103 Three
   4       1600        104 Four
   4                       Five
   4                       Six

12 rows selected
```

Notice that you can't outer join `L` even though at first glance it looks as though you can, because after the comment *Two joins below* there is only one join, which is on `R`.

```
select c.id, r.value, r.log_id, l.action
from   c
       left join r on r.c_id = c.id
       left join l on r.log_id = l.id
where  c.deleted is null
and    r.deleted is null
order by 1,2,3,4;

  ID      VALUE     LOG_ID ACTION
---- ---------- ---------- ------
   2        500        101 One
   2        600        102 Two
   2        700        103 Three
   2        800        104 Four
   4       1300        101 One
   4       1400        102 Two
   4       1500        103 Three
   4       1600        104 Four

8 rows selected
```

DBFiddle using 23c (select 11g to reproduce the old ORA-01417 error):
https://dbfiddle.uk/hCC-sxvv

Afterthought - I might be tempted to lay it out as below, to try to make it clearer that we are starting out with a Cartesian product of `C` and `L` and only then outer-joining `R` to that set:

```
select c.id
     , r.value, r.log_id
     , l.action
from   l cross join c
       left join r
            on  r.c_id = c.id
            and r.log_id = l.id
where  c.deleted is null
and    r.deleted is null
order by 1,2,3,4;
```

It's also possible that the OP accidentally wrote the final join condition the wrong way around, and actually meant to write this:

```
select c.id, r.value, r.log_id, l.action
from
    c, r, l
where
    c.deleted is null
    and r.deleted is null
    -- Two joins below
    and r.c_id(+) = c.id
    and l.id(+) = r.log_id
order by 1,2,3,4;
```

Which makes sense of the `from` clause and the *Two joins* comment, and matches Gordon's results, and would work in 11g unchanged.

I'd say this shows that the current syntax is clearer, as it is much harder to write a cross join by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "I never got my head around the "new" SQL join syntax".

Logically, a classical way to implement an outer join is as a *nested loop join*. I know that Oracle can perform the query in many different ways technically, but it helps in reasoning.

So you can imagine the outer join like a nested loop structure:

```
for rec_outer in outer_table:
   for rec_inner in matching_rows from inner_table:
       create a result row from rec_outer and rec_inner
   if no matching rows found in inner_table:
       create a result row from rec_outer and an all-NULL dummy record
```

The full syntax is:

```
FROM outer_table LEFT OUTER JOIN inner_table ON (...)
```

So, the OUTER table (which makes the outer loop)
is LEFT from the JOIN keyword.